# Having trouble converting a list to an int

Tags: python, list, int

Can anyone tell me why this will not output an int?

```
in_string = "1 2 3 4"
input_list = in_string.split(" ")
new_input_list = (input_list)
number = new_input_list
number = [int(i) for i in number]
print(number)
```

Comment: You are printing a list of ints

Comment: What the heck are you doing there? In the end, `number` is a list again, are you looking for `number[0]` ?

Comment: Your second last line create an array.

Comment: Output is `list` containing `integers`. What exactly you want?

Comment: What int were you expecting it to output? Also note that two of those lines are completely pointless.

Comment: `print(int(in_string.replace(" ",'')))`

Comment: Your penultimate line assigns number to a list of integers per the list comprehension.  You need to access its elements to get the integers, e.g. `number[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functional approach to mapping:

```
in_string = "1 2 3 4"
lst = list(map(int, in_string.split(' ')))
```

Then to print individual items:

```
for k in lst:
    print(k)
```

Or to access by location in list:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    print(lst[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using list comprehension

```
[int(i) for i in number]
```

So it is printing list of `int`